# Question about the square of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

> A graph H is the square of a graph $G$ if $V(H) = V(G)$ and $xy$ is an edge in $H$ if and only if  $x \neq y$ and the distance between x and y in G is at most two. Prove that for $n \geq 5$,
>   the square, $C_2^n$, of the cycle $C_n$ is planar if and only if $n$ is even.

For this question I am still confused on the concept of the square of a graph. It would increase the connectivity by adding an edge between any 2 vertices that have a distance of 2.

Comment: "*if and only if x = y*"  are you sure you don't want $x\neq y$?

Comment: It is not clear what confuses you. Yes, the square has more edges and therefore is "
more connected" than the original.

Comment: See the image on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power

Comment: As for a hint on how to proceed... for the odd case, consider $K_5$ and kuratowski's theorem.  For the even case, draw your cycle, and connect even vertices who are distance two apart from one another via an "inner" edge and odd vertices who are distance two apart via an "outer" edge.